# Why is Apache inserting comment into some of my HTML output?

Tags: php, apache

While running my code through W3C's HTML validator for HTML5, I noticed that some of my files had this comment inserted before the  tag:

```
<!-- This file should NOT be stored in the web root directory (or any sub-directory thereof) If this is not possible, place it in the 'include' directory and restrict access via Apache's .htaccess files -->
```

This only seems to happen with pages that are accessed via POST requests, though I have been unable to pin down any cause, nor have searches turned up anything.

I am using mod rewrites and the HTML is generated from multiple files from webroot/views/ and webroot/includes/, but other pages that are similarly generated do not have this issue.

Anyway, I normally wouldn't worry about it, but when sending an xml request to dynamically update a price field, the xml return results, which were supposed to be just the price value as a number, were prefixed by that entire comment.

Now, I can remove it in my application code, which is what I have done, but I'd really like to know under what circumstances Apache decides to inject this comment into outputted HTML files.

For reference, here is my JS to send/handle the xml request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * Updates the currently displayed price based on currently selected options
 * @param category_id   Id of currently selected category
 */
function updatePrice(category_id) {
    if (category_id === undefined || category_id < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName) { return; }
    var aSelect = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");
    var data = [];
    data.push("category_id=" + category_id);
    for (var i = 0; i < aSelect.length; i++) {
        var sid = aSelect[i].id;
        if (sid !== undefined && sid.indexOf("select_") > -1) {
            data.push(sid + '=' + aSelect[i].value);
        }
    }
    data = data.join('&');
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            // Hack to remove Apache's auto-generated comment/warning at top of some pages
            var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
            text = (text.length > 0 ? text.substring(text.lastIndexOf('>') + 1).trim() : '');
            var price = document.getElementById("product-price");
            if (price != null) {
                price.value = (text.length < 1 ? 'N/A' : ('$' + text));
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "rental_update_price.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}
</script>
```

And here is the php file that processes the request:

```
<?php

if (!isset($errors)) { $errors = array(); }
if (!isset($notifications)) { $notifications = array(); }

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (empty($_POST['category_id']) || !is_numeric($_POST['category_id'])) {
        die('Sorry, there has been a system error.');
    }
    $category_id = (int) $_POST['category_id'];

    require './includes/config.inc.php';
    require MYSQL;

    $att_tbl = selectWithCondition($dbc, 'att_table', 'rental_categories', 'id', $category_id, 'i', 'LIMIT 1');
    if ($att_tbl === FALSE) {
        die('Failed to retrieve product attribute table from database.');
    }
    // Retrieve all 'select' keys and values to query exact product id and price
    $selected = array();
    foreach($_POST AS $k=>$v) {
        if (strpos($k, 'select_') > -1) {
            // All select fields should be foreign key references, i.e. positive integers
            if (ctype_digit($v) && $v > 0) {
                $selected[(str_replace('select_', '', $k) . '_id')] = (int) $v;
            } else {
                $errors[$k] = 'Invalid value';
            }
        }
    }
    if (empty($selected)) {
        die('No columns selected.');
    }
    // TODO select price instead of id
    $q = "SELECT p.id FROM products p";
    $where = '';
    foreach($selected AS $k=>$v) {
        if (empty($where)) {
            $where = "t.$k=$v";
        } else {
            $where .= " AND t.$k=$v";
        }
    }
    $q .= " JOIN $att_tbl t ON t.product_id=p.id WHERE $where LIMIT 1";
    if (($r = $dbc->query($q))) {
        if ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
            // Generate dummy price value for testing:
            echo number_format((((int) $row['id']) * 31) / 100, 2);
        }
        $r->close();
    } else {
        $notifications['error'] = 'A system error has occurred. The system administrator will be notified automatically.';
        $notifications['error_log'] = 'Error No: ' . $dbc->errno . '-' . $dbc->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apache isn't doing this. What framework/system are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any framework - it's pure PHP/HTML, all coded the old-fashioned way. Is there any other information you need?

Comment: Does it help if you put the .js files in a different folder and include them via `<script>` with a `src` attribute? Maybe you can lock the problem down by checking the configuration of your apache server.

Comment: I'd download the whole set of code and do a find-in-files across it. It's likely to be generated somewhere in your code. Again, Apache wouldn't inject that sort of message.

Comment: that I haven't never seen or unlikely of apache; go to your source directory and issue > grep -i -r "<!-- This file" * to figure out in which file this comment is contained.

Comment: @ceejayoz Normally I would agree with you, but I've written every single line by hand and nowhere did I ever write anything like that. I wanted to blame my hosting service, but it also appears in the same files when testing on my local WAMP stack.

Comment: Check your `config.inc.php`

Comment: @Brian `grep` for it anyway...

Comment: What's this `require MYSQL;`.

Comment: I'm currently running findstr (I know, Windows >.<). Not turning anything up yet, but it's running very slowly.

Comment: MYSQL handles the database connection and is stored outside of the web root directory. Oh holy crap. There it is. Now don't I feel stupid :P

Comment: Now, how do I close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since it was one of those where you look for days and when you finally break down and ask, it becomes glaringly obvious almost immediately.

In my MYSQL file, I had that comment at the top, even before the php tags, and in certain situations the MYSQL file is included before any other HTML output, which then results in that comment being displayed.

Moving the comment to within the php tags so that it is not considered HTML fixes the issue.

Thanks to all who commented.

Answer (score 0):

```
require MYSQL;
```

if `MYSQL` is a file, give it an extension `.php` so it doesn't bypass the PHP interpreter.

I think PHP does print the warning when you include a file which is not parsed.